# jQuery binding on a newly appended element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I was curious if something like this was possible

```
$('.parent').append('<div></div>',
{ text: 'delete',
  on: {click, dofunc(this)}})
```

The key to this would be binding an event handler to a newly created element in its creation statement and passing the newly created element to the handler function.

Comment: Are you just curious as to how it can be done the way you have described or do you want to know how it can be done properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

```
$('<div/>', { 
  text:  'delete',
  click:  dofunc
}).appendTo('.parent');
```

`this` in the context of the `dofunc` function refers to the clicked element.

http://jsfiddle.net/e77L4/